# linux network setting POST failing after exactly 2 hours

Tags: java, httpurlconnection, recv

I have following test code running fine for a very long POST request (more than 2 hours):

```
        URL postURL = new URL(url);            
        con = (HttpURLConnection) postURL.openConnection();            
        con.setUseCaches(false);
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        con.setDoInput(true);
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");            
        OutputStream out = con.getOutputStream();
        OutputStreamWriter wout = new OutputStreamWriter(out, "UTF-8");
        wout.write(xmlRequest);
        wout.flush();
        out.close();
        con.connect();            
        int httpResponseCode = HttpURLConnection.HTTP_SERVER_ERROR;
        try {
            httpResponseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log(e.toString() + " Error retrieving the status code");
        }
        log("Failure status code " + httpResponseCode + " received: ");
```

I run this post from one host to another and it runs fine in all environments, except one exact linux redhat host -when i run this code from this host I got exception:

java.net.SocketException: recv() failed, errno = 104 Connection reset by peer Error retrieving the status code
Failure status code 500 received.

Target server host is the same host in all tests. So the difference is only in client caller host.

So I'm trying to understand what exact tcp setting on this linux machine is causing receive to fail after exactly 2 hours.

I agree to get any blame here for such "incorrect" using of the sending post and waiting for more then 2 hours for response;) but question is what causing this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the difference was that one client host was on different network segment and router was killing idle sessions after timeout.

Answer (score 0):

google for 7200 seconds tcp redhat and among other things

```
   tcp_keepalive_time (integer; default: 7200; since Linux 2.2)
          The number of seconds a connection needs to be idle  before  TCP
          begins sending out keep-alive probes.  Keep-alives are only sent
          when the SO_KEEPALIVE socket option  is  enabled.   The  default
          value  is  7200 seconds (2 hours).  An idle connection is termi-
          nated after approximately an additional 11 minutes (9 probes  an
          interval of 75 seconds apart) when keep-alive is enabled.

          Note that underlying connection tracking mechanisms and applica-
          tion timeouts may be much shorter.
```

Comment: There are other timeouts if you google around, like masquerading session timeout, as well.